# Alert when azure function returns a value

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-alerts

I have an azure function that checks if a blob file exists or not. This function returns true or false, and I want to send an alert if the outout is false. (This function is in python)

Comment: what sort of alert? an email? a message to a service bus topic/queue? an EvenHub event?

Comment: An email without using sendgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you haven't provided any sample code, the first thing you should look at is the developer reference to ensure your logs are being created correctly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#logging

I'd recommend you look at the Monitor Azure Functions page and ensure you have Application Insights enabled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring

Then you can use the following guide on how to query and analyse the App Insights data:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data

You may have to timeslice or aggregate the data for failures in `x` number of minutes.

Comment: async def main(name: str) -> bool:
    
    connect_str = os.getenv('AzureWebStorage')
    blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connect_str, container_name="testcsv", blob_name=name)
    exists = blob.exists()
    
    if(exists):
        logging.info(f"The blob exists \n")
    
    else:
        logging.info(f"The blob does not exist \n")
    return exists

Comment: So using `logging.info` you should be able to write a log analytics query which identifies any new logs generated and use an Alert rule: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log to generate an alert. If you don't want to use SendGrid then you will have to provide an SMTP relay or REST SMTP service to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

You could add mail functionality to the function itself, using the MS Graph API. The function would need `Mail.Send` permission. For sending email from a Python function you could look at [this resource](https://kontext.tech/article/795/python-send-email-via-microsoft-graph-api).

If you need to send the email outwith Azure, just invoke the `HTTP` function via its URL, check the output and send the email if required. You could make the function return some `JSON` for example:

```
{
  "result": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a function in python, if any blob doesn't exist in container, then it will send a mail through Microsoft graph API.

**Python Function**

```py
import logging
import json
import msal
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

import azure.functions as func
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('function processed a request.')
connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=functionblob28789;AccountKey=xxxxxx.windows.net"

container_name = "images"
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, container_name=container_name)
files = blob.GetBlobsAsync()
condition = false
if files = ! null
condition = true
else
// Send a mail using Microsoft graph API.

print(condition)
```

In `else` part you can send a mail by using `Microsoft Graph API`.

Refer the following [documentation](https://kontext.tech/article/795/python-send-email-via-microsoft-graph-api)  for sending an email via Microsoft Graph API by Raymond.